# Why my code leaking memory after many function calls? Is ClassLoader a problem?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, classloader

i have a mehod getAllTests() that load external jar in a folder and with Reflection search method with Annotation Test (@Test).
I use:

`URLClassLoader` class for load Jar File;

`Class currentClass=child.loadClass(classname);` for load class;

`Method method = currentClass.getMethods()[i];`

`Annotation annTest = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);`

for get Method and get Annotation.

My code is this:

```
public static void getAllTests() throws IllegalArgumentException,  NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException,LinkageError, ClassNotFoundException {
        TestLoaderApplication.testClassObjMap.clear(); <--is a HashMap class
        LoadLibrary loadLibrary=new LoadLibrary();<--used for search all file .jar in folder
        List<JarFile> jarList= loadLibrary.getListJar(pathJars).stream().map(f -> {
            try {
                return new JarFile(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (JarFile j : jarList) {
            URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(
                    new URL[] {new File(j.getName()).toURI().toURL()},
                    ServiceUtil.class.getClassLoader()
            );

            for (Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = j.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                String file = entry.getName();
                if (file.endsWith(".class")) {
                    String classname = file.replaceAll("/", ".")
                            .substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("."));
                    try {

                        Class currentClass=child.loadClass(classname);
                        List<String> testMethods = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < currentClass.getMethods().length; i++) {
                            Method method = currentClass.getMethods()[i];
                            Annotation annTest = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
                            Annotation annTestFactory = method.getAnnotation(TestFactory.class);
                            if (annTest != null || annTestFactory != null) {
                                testMethods.add(method.getName());
                            }
                        }//fine for metodi
                        if (testMethods.size() >=1) {
                            testClassObjMap.put(j.getName().substring(j.getName().lastIndexOf("\\")+1),classname,testMethods);
                            TestLoaderApplication.testClassObjMap.put(j.getName().substring(j.getName().lastIndexOf("/")+1),classname,testMethods);
                            LOGGER.info(String.format("%s %s %s",j.toString(),classname,testMethods));
                        }
                    }catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
                        LOGGER.warn("WARNING: failed NoClassDefFoundError " + classname + " from " + file);
                    }
                    catch (Throwable e) {
                        LOGGER.warn("WARNING: failed to instantiate " + classname + " from " + file);
                    }

                }//if .class

            }//chiudo jarentry for
            j.close();
            child.close();
            child=null;
        }//chiudo jarfile for
        System.gc();
        LOGGER.info("Test Loader Console Back-End:\tFine Reflection Scan");

    }
```

At end of this function i close both JarFile(j) and classLoader(child) and set child=null and agter call garbage collector.
But if i call this method many times at end i have about 100% memory used by java webapps.

This method is in a spring-boot project and i use Tomcat for webserver.

Can you recommend some optimization in the use of the classLoader and if this is the correct way to look for methods with annotation @Test in Java?
Thanks

Comment: haven't looked at the code, but will suggest tool like jvisualvm to check memory consumtion

Comment: jvisualvm  i cant use it on unix server, i dont have root privilage

Comment: I see you already trying to garbage collect classloader, so if nothing else works, maybe processing each jar in separate JVM and then discarding it as brute-force solution should solve memory leak